# 20.04 Ubuntu Software Issue, software not appearing

Tags: software-center

It's been a while since i opened Ubuntu Software. I opened it and it was like in the image linked below. i did not try rebooting or things like that so i dont know if that will work. what could be the issue then?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you can try to update the software list. Use this command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Also, check if your sources (e.g. universe) is enabled in Software & Updates.